# Shiny + SQLite - why is Shiny extremely slow?

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

We have developing a Shiny app for a few months now. But our Shiny app is **extremely slow** when it tries to load a **huge amount of data**. We even use the `reactive` function to reuse the data. But it is still slow as before when we request different sets of data.

We have a log file and it shows that Shiny takes **at least** 30.12672 seconds or 52.24799 seconds each time to load the data from our database.

What are the reasons make Shiny so slow? Is it the **server** or the database? What can we do to speed it up?

We are using SQLite database. Is it the reason that makes Shiny slow?

If so, what other types of database system should we go for to process huge amount of data sets? Cassandra? HBase? Apache Spark?

**EDIT:**

For instace,

```
query <- "SELECT
    s.timestamp,
    s.particle_concentration as `PM2.5`,
    n.code as site
    FROM speckdata AS s

    LEFT JOIN nodes AS n
    ON n.nid = s.nid
    AND n.datatype = 'speck'

    WHERE strftime('%Y', s.localdate) = 'YEAR'
"

# Match the pattern and replace it.
dataQuery <- sub("YEAR", as.character(year), query)

# Store the result in data1.
data = dbGetQuery(DB, dataQuery)

if(nrow(data) > 0) {

    # Convert timestamp to date and bind it to the data.
    data$date <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(data$timestamp)), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")
}


    # Chosen to group the data in one panel.
    timePlot(
        data,
        pollutant = c(species, condition),
        avg.time = avg_time,
        lwd = 2,
        lty = 1,
        name.pol = c(species_text_value, condition_text_value),
        type = "site",
        group = TRUE,
        auto.text = FALSE
    )
```

That is extremely slow in Shiny.

But when we query the data set using the SQLite manager, it only takes **1.9 seconds for 4719282 rows**!

[image]

Comment: How huge are we talking? How exactly do you interact with the SQLite backend? Have you tried measuring performance of your queries without shiny?

Comment: `Have you tried measuring performance of your queries without shiny` - how do I measure erformance of your queries without shiny?

Comment: `How exactly do you interact with the SQLite backend?` - by using SQLite queries.

Comment: `How huge are we talking? How exactly do you interact with the SQLite backend? ` about 14,000 rows at least.

Comment: The data are stored in a .sqlite3 file. Please see my edit above how i query the data without Shiny.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest testing the performance of your SQLite query directly off the database. If that's your slow point you will want to optimize your query to make it more efficient. Before I can help further it would be good to know exactly where the performance issues are.

Comment: `I would suggest testing the performance of your SQLite query directly off the database.` - we query the data set using the SQLite manager, it only takes 1.9 seconds for 4719282 rows. (please check this out in the screen grab I made above). Thanks.

Comment: It appears that your query is working fine. Is the app performing any other preprocessing?  If it is I would use the "Sys.time()" to get  a better idea where the slowness is coming from. Put those in your code and run it by hand (don't run the shiny app), it will give you a better idea where you may need to fix the app.